# Cross-origin access with jQuery: accessing frames in subdomain in Internet Explorer fails

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-domain

If iframe tag with the source from subdomain is already in the document when it loads, it can be accessed by IE9, but if the same iframe is inserted in document, IE9 cannot access it (all other browsers can). Please see code snippets below.

Is it normal IE9 behaviour or can it be somehow fixed? Google wasn't helpful this time, so I would really appreciate your help here.

**This works in Internet Explorer 9 and all other browsers**

Main document in example.com:

```
<div class="container">
    <iframe src="sub.example.com/index.html"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
    document.domain = 'example.com';
    var frame = $('iframe', 'container')
        , el = frame.contents().find('div.hello'); // usually returns 1 element
    if (el.length > 0)
        el.html('Hello'); // sets div content in iframe
    else // sometimes it gets here, if script runs before iframe loads
        frame.on('load', function(){
            el = frame.contents().find('div.hello'); // works if the 1st one fails
            el.html('Hello');
        });
</script>
```

Document in subdomain (sub.example.com/index.html):

```
<script>document.domain = 'example.com'</script>
<div class="hello"></div>
```

**This works in all browsers but not in IE9 (Error: Access is denied)**

Main document in example.com:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<script>
    $('div.container').html('<iframe src="sub.example.com/index.html"></iframe>');
    document.domain = 'example.com';
    var frame = $('iframe', 'container')
        , el = frame.contents().find('div.hello'); // throws error

    // ...
</script>
```

Document in subdomain is the same.

In real code the contents of .container are generated by template function so it is inserted as simple text using .html(), like in example.

Thanks for any help to make the second case work in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because in the second case the script that sets the frame's document.domain is executed after frame's load event fires. Putting the code inside frame.ready() doesn't help - frame becomes ready before the script executes. It happens this way in all browsers, but only cause error in IE for some reason.

So the current solution is a hack really - 100ms timeout after frame becomes ready so that the script inside frame executes before the frame is accessed.